# NodeJS: Why util.isFunction does not exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking at source code of 'util' module you can see [`isFunction`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L569) method definition:

```
function isFunction(arg) {
   return typeof arg === 'function';
};
exports.isFunction = isFunction;
```

But when I run node, 'isFunction' is missing in util library:

```
var util = require('util');
'isFunction' in util; //false
```

What am I missing? Where 'isFunction' method is being deleted from 'util'?

Comment: Maybe you require a node module called util? Try `require('./util.js')`

Comment: @NULL I have no my own module with name 'util'. `require('./util.js')` results: `Error: Cannot find module './util.js'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're looking at the code for the master branch, v0.11. you're testing it on a stable branch, probably v0.10.x, which doesn't have these utilities yet.

Comment: Yeah! You're right! I was testing it on v0.10.25 version. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Also I suggest you to use a module called `lodash`